# How can I use opencv.js in Typescript?

Tags: typescript, opencv

Instruction on openCV websites guides to prepare codes like this, but how can I use this and apply in TypeScript?

Writing this as a `.js` file works perfectly fine, but putting it into `.ts` keeps throwing error TS7017 on the

`global.Module` and `global.cv` part asking me for type.

Does anyone have any idea how we can implement opencv in a TypeScript project?

Thanks! Happy Coding!!

```
const { Canvas, createCanvas, Image, ImageData, loadImage } = require('canvas');
const { JSDOM } = require('jsdom');
const { writeFileSync, existsSync, mkdirSync } = require("fs");
// This is our program. This time we use JavaScript async / await and promises to handle asynchronicity.
(async () => {
  // before loading opencv.js we emulate a minimal HTML DOM. See the function declaration below.
  installDOM();
  await loadOpenCV();
  // using node-canvas, we an image file to an object compatible with HTML DOM Image and therefore with cv.imread()
  const image = await loadImage('./lena.jpg');
  const src = cv.imread(image);
  const dst = new cv.Mat();
  const M = cv.Mat.ones(5, 5, cv.CV_8U);
  const anchor = new cv.Point(-1, -1);
  cv.dilate(src, dst, M, anchor, 1, cv.BORDER_CONSTANT, cv.morphologyDefaultBorderValue());
  // we create an object compatible HTMLCanvasElement
  const canvas = createCanvas(300, 300);
  cv.imshow(canvas, dst);
  writeFileSync('output.jpg', canvas.toBuffer('image/jpeg'));
  src.delete();
  dst.delete();
})();
// Load opencv.js just like before but using Promise instead of callbacks:
function loadOpenCV() {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    global.Module = {
      onRuntimeInitialized: resolve
    };
    global.cv = require('./opencv.js');
  });
}
// Using jsdom and node-canvas we define some global variables to emulate HTML DOM.
// Although a complete emulation can be archived, here we only define those globals used
// by cv.imread() and cv.imshow().
function installDOM() {
  const dom = new JSDOM();
  global.document = dom.window.document;
  // The rest enables DOM image and canvas and is provided by node-canvas
  global.Image = Image;
  global.HTMLCanvasElement = Canvas;
  global.ImageData = ImageData;
  global.HTMLImageElement = Image;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A very crude workaround is this:

```
(global as any).Module = {
```